# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3. shows error

Tags: android, maven, gradle, configuration, android-studio-3.0

> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.Could not get resource https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
>
> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad request
>
> Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0.Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.2.0/google-services-4.2.0.pom'.

Yesterday I update Android Studio in gradle 3.5.3 above error. I have tried to find out mistake but I am unable.

Comment: Add your `build.gradle` file

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() //HAVE YOU MISS IT?
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Answer (score 0):

Follow below simple steps.

1. Check your internet connection, if it works then,
2. Check the firewall to see some of the `Google Service` blocks or not.
3. Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio.

Comment: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom use above link in search bar its shows {
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Could not find resource"
  } ]
}

Comment: check is it accessible or not : https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom

Comment: it's accessible but still shows Could not find resource check other network LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Android 3.5

Solution  : Add Google Maven repository to Android Studio Project.

Discover solution at : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgYksTDY1nw
or https://android-er.blogspot.com/2019/03/add-google-maven-repository-to-android.html

take care
Vinc:)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solved this error in our school where we used network "proxy" settings. The error is always [Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.] from old version of Android Studio SDK even the new one 3.6.1. Below are the steps I made:

1. Check your Network Settings -> Proxy -> Use a Proxy Server (TURN IT OFF)
2. Check Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections -> Ethernet Properties -> IPV4 Properties -> Change to obtained (or you set it with your common network IP)
3. Open the file gradle.properties location C:\Users\.gradle\  and remove all the settings related to "proxy" which makes the Android error in classpath.

That's it.